# How can I create a shortcut to change: "number of verticle" , "number of cuts"?

Tags: python, shortcut

With out scrolling mouse or F6, or ToolBar "T". I want to use my own hotkey "inside any Tool" . Like: Q, W - to raise or down "Number of cuts" in loopCutAndSlide; Q,w - to raise or down "Segments" in addUvSphere ... In input editor there is nothing suitable. Only Pyton? Tell me what should i type ... maybe some example. Thank you! [image]